# How to add a texture file to an Android Studio project

Tags: android, opengl-es

Many examples use the resources infrastructure to load textures. I'd like to debug a problem, so I want to use the most simple, complication-free solution.

When I try to add an image asset to my project (with New > Image Asset) I'm getting the usual GUI, which will generate HDPI, XHDPI etc. versions. This is clearly not intended for textures. - So what is the *right* way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most app stores texture and background images in asset folder. If you want to store it in the resources only then you can use **drawable** folder.

For layout problem you can choose **Project** from dropdown and choose the folder.